# how to refresh cookies in angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, session-cookies, httpcookie

I have an angular web aplication 
in index.html the code wrote

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $cookieStore, $location, $window) {
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
    if ($cookieStore.get('username') == null) {
        $window.location.href = '/report/login.html';
    } else {
    }

});
```

});

with above code i try to change become ***/regist/index.html*** and the changes have been saved,
but when I try to access it, the web page still directed to old location not newest **location href** I try to refresh several times nothing changes, finally I try to disabled cache in developer tools and refresh it, 
how to fix it guys need your help.

Comment: when you dissabled the cache is it fixed?

Comment: yes,, i disabled it and refresh the browser it change to newest code I wrote

Answer (score 1):

you can maintain a version index of you application then add that version as urls suffix.

```
var appVersion = '1.0';

app.run(function ($rootScope, $cookieStore, $location, $window) {
 $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
    if ($cookieStore.get('username') == null) {
        $window.location.href = '/report/login.html?v=' + appVersion;
    } else {
    }

 });
});
```

or random number as url suffix

```
 $window.location.href = '/report/login.html?v=' +  Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
```

I am not recommend for adding random numbers

Comment: it still doesn't work i still must to disabled and enabled cache an refresh

Comment: did u try random number method?